# Using binomal distribution with Spark to calculate an expected value and a variance ("number of times getting a six when throwing a dice three times")

Tags: apache-spark, statistics

I'm training myself to resolve classical statistics exercices with `Spark` and it's `MLib` module when needed, in order to face any situation later.

`Spark` is dedicated to calculation on matrices, but let's say that I have a side calculation to do in my program, at a time, and that I would like to resolve it with `Spark`, without adding others APIs.

> The calculation is simple : learn the expected value and the variance 
>   of having a *six* on a dice, when you throw it three times.

Currently, I resolve it by the help of the `Apache maths` API and a bit of `Spark` :

```java
/** Among imports : */
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.*;

/**
 * E8.5 : On lance trois dés. Probabilité d'un six obtenu ?
 * Suit une loi binomiale B(3, 1/6)
 * Par calcul : F(0) = 125/216, F(1) = 125/216 + 75/216, F(2) = (125 + 75 + 15)/216, 
 * F(3) = (125 + 75 + 15 + 1)/216 = 1  
 */
@Test
@DisplayName("On lance trois dés. Probabilité d'un six obtenu ?. Caractéristiques de la loi B(3, 1/6)")
public void troisDésDonnentUnSix() {
   int n = 3;                    // Nombre de lancés de dés.
   double v[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};    // Valeurs possibles de la variable aléatoire.
   double f[] = new double[n+1]; // Fréquences cumulées.
   double p[] = new double[n+1]; // Probabilités.

   // Calculer les probabilités et les fréquences.
   BinomialDistribution loiBinomale = new BinomialDistribution(n, 1.0/6.0);

   for(int i=0; i <= n; i++) {
      p[i] = loiBinomale.probability(i);
      f[i] = loiBinomale.cumulativeProbability(i);   
   }

   LOGGER.info("P(x) = {}", p);
   LOGGER.info("F(x) = {}", f);

   Dataset<Row> ds = fromDouble(v, p);
   LOGGER.info("E(X) = {}, V(X) = {}", esperance(ds), variance(ds));
}
```

where `fromDouble(v, p)` method creates a `Dataset` from a list of random variable values (column `x`) and their associated frequencies (column `Px`) :

```java
/**
 * Renvoyer un Dataset depuis une série de valeurs entières à probabilités.
 * @param valeurs Valeurs.
 * @param probabilites Probabilités.
 * @return Dataset avec une colonne x, entière, contenant les valeurs<br>
 * et une colonne Px, décimale, contenant les probabilités.
 */
protected Dataset<Row> fromDouble(double[] valeurs, double[] probabilites) {
   StructType schema = new StructType()
      .add("x", DoubleType, false)
      .add("Px", DoubleType, false);

   List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();

   for(int index=0; index < valeurs.length; index ++) {
      rows.add(RowFactory.create(valeurs[index], probabilites[index]));
   }

   return this.session.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
}
```

And esperance (= expected value) and variance methods called are doing these calculations :

```java
/**
 * Calculer l'espérance sur un Dataset avec valeurs et probabilités.
 * @param ds Dataset avec colonnes : <br>
 * x  : valeur<br>
 * Px : fréquence<br>
 * @return espérance.
 */
protected double esperance(Dataset<Row> ds) {
   return ds.agg(sum(col("x").multiply(col("Px")))).first().getDouble(0);
}

/**
 * Calculer la variance sur un Dataset avec valeurs et probabilités.
 * @param ds Dataset avec colonnes : <br>
 * x  : valeur<br>
 * Px : fréquence<br>
 * @return espérance.
 */
protected double variance(Dataset<Row> ds) {
   Column variation = col("x").minus(esperance(ds));
   Column variationCarre = variation.multiply(variation);
   Column termeCalculVariance = col("Px").multiply(variationCarre);

   return ds.agg(sum(termeCalculVariance)).first().getDouble(0);
}
```

LOGGER output :

```
P(x) = [0.5787037037037037, 0.34722222222222215, 0.06944444444444445, 0.0046296296296296285]
F(x) = [0.5787037037037035, 0.9259259259259259, 0.9953703703703703, 1.0]
E(X) = 0.49999999999999994, V(X) = 0.41666666666666663
```

It works (? I have caculatd by hand "E(X) = 53/108", and it finds 54/108 = 0.5..., I might be wrong), but it's not perfect.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem using `Spark` (and `Spark-MLib`, if needed) ?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I get E(X) = 1/2 and Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 2/3 - (1/2)^2 = 5/12, after a few minutes of working with it. About using Spark, my advice is to try to parallelize the processing as much as possible. Parallelizing the trials is simple -- just create a parallel array (I forget what's called in Spark ... there has been substantial evolution over the years and I don't know what's considered up-to-date) and store the result of one trial in each element. Computing E(X) and Var(X) are a little more subtle.

Comment: The good news is that E(X) and E(X^2) can be computed from subsets of X and X^2  because n (i.e., number of elements), sum(X), and sum(X^2) are so-called sufficient statistics of the binomial distribution. So you can compute n, sum(X), and sum(X^2) from each block of a distributed array and then compute the overall n, sum(X), and sum(X^2) from those intermediate results.